# How to integrate algolia with realtime database firebase in angular 6 application.

Tags: firebase, angular6, algolia

I am using angular 6 latest version. I have already install firebase and algolia in my angular app, but my query is how to integrate realtime database with algolia.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Algolia to search the content you have in Firebase you have to send it to Algolia for indexing. Typically you would do that from a NodeJS server or some Cloud Functions.

There is a short guide in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) and a more in depth [guide from Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/3rd-party-service/firebase-algolia/).